# How can I generate a unique key from 2 strings?

Tags: python

Let's say I have "username1" and "username2"

How can I combine these two usernames together to generate a unique value?

The value should be the same no matter how they are combined if username2 is entered first or vice versa the two names should always combine to become the same unique value. The string length will not work as other usernames can have the same length.

Is there a simple way to do this or a technique for this?

Comment: How guaranteed unique does it need to be? `hash(frozenset({user1, user2}))` will be highly unlikely to duplicate precisely, but there's no guarantee (read up on the birthday paradox; on a 64 bit Python build, the number of possible results is `2 ** 64`, which isn't likely to collide for a moderate number of values, but the odds go up for more and more inputs). Some equivalent approach xor-ing bytes of cryptographic hashes reduces collision probabilities further, but again, can't *guarantee* uniqueness.

Comment: What does "value" mean? For example, `tuple(sorted([name1, name2]))` will give a unique value that can be used as a dict key (or set element, etc)) - but it's a 2-tuple.

Comment: @TimPeters: Good point. I assumed they meant "scalar value", but an actual `frozenset` or sorted `tuple` of the original values would work better (being lossless) if collections of values work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sets are unordered, and Python has a hashable immutable set type, assuming your requirement for a unique key is that it can be used as a dict key:

```py
def key(a, b):
    return frozenset([a, b])

d = {}
d[key("foo", "bar")] = "baz"
print(d[key("bar", "foo")])
```

You can also create a sorted tuple:

```py
def key(a, b):
    return tuple(sorted([a, b]))

d = {}
d[key("foo", "bar")] = "baz"
print(d[key("bar", "foo")])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to generate a unique value.  One common (to sysops) method is the one used to get a UNIX UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) from the routines supplied with most major languages.  In case of parsing problems, use a separator that does not appear in your input strings.

If  you replace my constant strings "username1" and "username2" with your variables, I believe that your problem is solved.

```
import uuid
unique_sep = '|'    # I posit vertical bar as not appearing in any user name

import uuid
unique_ID = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_X500, "username1" + unique_sep + "username2")
print(unique_ID)
```

Output:

```
b2106742-94f5-596d-a461-c977b5982d85
```

To preserve uniqueness from entry order, simply sort them in any convenient fashion, such as:

```
names_in = [username1, username2]
unique_ID = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_X500, min(names_in) + unique_sep + max(names_in))
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem like it meets the requirement of “The value should be the same no matter how they are combined if username2 is entered first or [vice] versa”.

Comment: Ah -- no, it doesn't.  One has to "sort" them.  Let me edit ...

Comment: I actually really like this solution. Simple and works as intended with the sorting. Thanks.